# Python 2.5 and lists in function arguments

Tags: python, python-2.5

I'm trying to accomplish something in Python2.5

So I have my function

```
def f(a,b,c,d,e):
    pass
```

and now I'd like to call that function: (in python2.7 I would do)

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3)
f(0, *my_tuple, e=4)
```

But there is no way to do it in python2.5. I'm thinking about apply()

```
apply(f, something magical here)

#this doesn't work - multiple value for 'a'. But it's the only thing I came up with
apply(f, my_tuple, {"a":0, "e":4})
```

How would you do it? I'd like to do it inline, without putting things in list before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to swap the order of arguments then you could use something like this:

```
>>> def f(a,b,c,d,e):
...  print a,b,c,d,e
...
>>> my_tuple = (1,2,3)
>>> def apply(f, mid, *args, **kwargs):
...  return f(*args+mid, **kwargs)
...
>>> apply(f, my_tuple, 0, e=4)
0 1 2 3 4
>>>
>>> apply(f, ('a', 'b'), '_', d='c', e='d')
_ a b c d
>>>
```